# How get access token from other users

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I need to read the posts on facebook. I had create the application and the program works if I log with my credential. But when I log with another credential ( like another profile that I have just created) the program doesn't work anymore. This is my login page:

```
$config = array(
        'appId' => APPID,
        'secret' => APPSECRET,
        'allowSignedRequest' => false // optional but should be set to false for non-canvas apps
);

$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$user_id = $facebook->getUser();

if(!empty($_SESSION)) {

if($user_id) {


    try {

        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');




        $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'user_posts'));
        $access_token=$facebook->getAccessToken();
        $facebook->setAccessToken($access_token);

    } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {


        error_log($e->getType());
        error_log($e->getMessage());
    }
}
} else {



    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'user_posts'));

    header("Location: ".$login_url);

}
```

when I login I obtain the access token and I call graph api:

> https://graph.facebook.com/******/posts?access_token=**

This is operation work if I m who is logged in the application. If another login in the app this is not work.
Maybe it's a authentication problem. Maybe I forget some operation that I must do to authentica with another account. Anyone can help me?

Comment: different user, different access keys.

Comment: Yes but How i can obtain this access key.

Comment: you need to create an app under that diffferent user, far as I know. Might be another way, but I don't know it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to submit your App to Facebook then Facebook will check and pass you app then you can access you app other account. If you want to check App Functionality you can use Facebook App test user Id. Below I have Explained how to get test user

1. Goto App Page.
2. Click on Roles.
3. Click on to Right Corner Test users.
4. It will show your test user details.
5. Use this details and access you App.

Comment: how I can submitthe app to facebook? I don't believe to test app for now I need to work with another account

Comment: @GRA  Follow this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/how-to-submit https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/submission-process

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your app public for all users from here: https://developers.facebook.com

have a look on it:
[image]

Comment: I had just done this step. Thank you for your suggest!

Comment: What is "start a submission"?

Comment: facebook by default provides access to the public profile and email address only to have privilege to post on on users profile and others, you have to submit your items for which you want permission

Comment: After the review by facebook developers you will get permission for requested items

Comment: for this you must have to full fill some basic criteria like you must have privacy policy page etc.etc

Comment: I don't think that my problem is in this button!! I'm tring whit my  admin accounts and it works but if I try with another account it doesn't work. Fo ryou what is it?

Answer (score 0):

Use **/me/feed** instead of **/me** in your API call

see example below

**Permissions**

- Your app needs **user_posts permission** from the person who created the post or the person tagged in the post. Then your app can read:
- Timeline posts from the person who gave you the permission.
- The posts that other people made on that person Timeline.
- The posts that other people have tagged that person in.
- If you attempt to read data from a feed that your app has not been authorized to access, the call will return an empty array.

please read this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30719556/read-post-from-facebook-home/30732874#30732874

**READING**

```
/* PHP SDK v4.0.0 */
/* make the API call */
$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'GET',
  '/me/feed'
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
/* handle the result */
```